# How do I change (enlarge) the font size of a phrase in my answer?

Tags: support, markdown

How do I change (enlarge) the font size of a line in my answer?  I read about formatting (markdown) in the Help area, but did not see this aspect covered there.

Comment: It doesn't mean you should use that during posting for anything but headers, though. Almost all browsers can zoom in and out these days.

Comment: @DeerHunter It's for a particular line, not the whole answer!

Comment: The answers below are nice. On another note, on sites where MathJax is turned on, you have more size options using/misusing LaTeX. (I really don't find it necessary to have that many options though, people aren't writing books here)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you are talking about larger headers like:

## This large font

### This medium font

#### Or this smaller font

---

These are accomplished using leading `#` on their own line. One `#` produces the largest header, above. Two `##` produces the medium sized font. Three `###` produces the smallest.

```
# This large font
## This medium font
### Or this smaller font
```

Comment: I discovered that to get this to work, I have to remove the bold formatting (enclosing phrase in double asterisks); the header formatting apparently automatically bolds the text.  (Which makes sense, only I didn't realize this at first.)

Answer (score 6):

You can't increase the font size with specific sizes (ie. can't say `10px`).

The best you can do is:

## Header (`# Header`)

### Header (`## Header`)

#### Header (`### Header`)

Comment: what if you want a size for a paragraph or phrase?instead of titles and headers

Comment: @maheshmnj That isn't really possible in Markdown, maybe consider using asterisks for bold/italics if you want to emphasise specific text instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use html tags like below ↓↓↓

---

<h1>Hello</h1>

## Hello

---

<h2>Hello</h2>

### Hello

---

<h3>Hello</h3>

#### Hello

---

Hello (Default Size)

---

In addition, you can use one or more "----------"(Hyphens) after one or more lines of text.

Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello 
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑

## Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

---

Also, you can use one or more "=========="(Equals) after one or more lines of text.

Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello H0ello Hello Hello 
==========

### Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

---